# Dijkstra's algorithm in Rust

Tags: algorithm, graph, rust

I'd love to get feedback on my first go at Dijkstra's algorithm in Rust:

```
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::{BinaryHeap, HashMap};
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let s = Vertex::new("s");
    let t = Vertex::new("t");
    let x = Vertex::new("x");
    let y = Vertex::new("y");
    let z = Vertex::new("z");

    // A map from vertices to their adjacent vertices including costs
    let mut adjacency_list = HashMap::new();
    adjacency_list.insert(&s, vec![(&t, 10), (&y, 5)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(&t, vec![(&y, 2), (&x, 1)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(&x, vec![(&z, 4)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(&y, vec![(&t, 3), (&x, 9), (&z, 2)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(&z, vec![(&s, 7), (&x, 6)]);

    dijkstra(&s, &adjacency_list);

    adjacency_list.keys().for_each(|v| println!("{:?}", v));
}

// Multiple lifetime parameters to avoid the error:
// "borrowed value does not live long enough"
fn dijkstra<'a, 's: 'a>(
    start: &'a Vertex<'s>,
    adjacency_list: &'a HashMap<&'a Vertex<'s>, Vec<(&'a Vertex<'s>, usize)>>,
) {
    start.distance.set(0);

    // Fill the binary heap, vertices with the smallest distance go first
    let mut to_visit = BinaryHeap::new();
    adjacency_list.keys().for_each(|v| to_visit.push(*v));

    // We visit the vertices with the smallest distance first, this is
    // what makes Dijkstra a greedy algorithm
    while let Some(v) = to_visit.pop() {
        if let Some(neighbors) = adjacency_list.get(v) {
            for (n, cost) in neighbors {
                let new_distance = v.distance.get() + cost;
                if new_distance < n.distance.get() {
                    n.distance.set(new_distance);
                    // n.predecessor.set(Some(Rc::new(*v)));
                }
            }
            // When changing a vertex' distance, the BinaryHeap doesn't
            // update the position of the vertex.
            // That's why we create a new heap with the right order.
            let mut new_heap = BinaryHeap::new();
            to_visit.iter().for_each(|x| new_heap.push(*x));
            to_visit = new_heap;
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Eq)]
struct Vertex<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    distance: Cell<usize>,
    // predecessor: Cell<Option<Rc<Vertex<'a>>>>,
}

impl<'a> Vertex<'a> {
    fn new(name: &'a str) -> Vertex<'a> {
        Vertex {
            name,
            distance: Cell::new(usize::max_value()),
            // predecessor: Cell::new(None),
        }
    }
}
impl<'a> Hash for Vertex<'a> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.name.hash(state);
    }
}

/// Since this Vertex will be put in a priority queue where the vertices
/// with the *smallest* distance should be processed first, `cmp`
/// returns GT if self.distance().get() < other.distance().get()
impl<'a> Ord for Vertex<'a> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Vertex<'a>) -> Ordering {
        other.distance.get().cmp(&self.distance.get())
    }
}
impl<'a> PartialOrd for Vertex<'a> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Vertex<'a>) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}
impl<'a> PartialEq for Vertex<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Vertex<'a>) -> bool {
        self.name == other.name
    }
}

impl<'a> Debug for Vertex<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "name: {}, distance: {:?}",
            self.name,
            self.distance.get()
        )
    }
}
```

Things I'd especially like to improve and simplify, if possible:

- Type signatures: I've wrestled a bit with the borrow checker to get rid of "borrowed value doesn't live long enough". As a consequence I had to introduce (multiple) lifetime parameters at a couple of places
- BinaryHeap: At first it seemed like a good data structure to have fast access to the vertex with the smallest distance. But since BinaryHeap doesn't resort the values when they change, I had to improvise (and incur worse performance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **Pay attention to compiler warnings**. Rust is a statically-compiled language. One of the big reasons you choose such a language is to get information at compile time:

   ```
   warning: unused import: `std::rc::Rc`
    --> src/main.rs:7:5
     |
   7 | use std::rc::Rc;
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default
   ```
2. Modern Rust coalesces imports from the same crate.
3. You are inconsistent with your usage of `for` loops and `for_each`. Have a reason for using one or the other.
4. `dijkstra` requires no lifetime generics, so don't include them.
5. Don't have commented out code; that's what source control is for.
6. It feels very wrong to have `Eq` and `Hash` not working from the same data. This is undoubtedly sure to cause problems in the future.
7. It feels very wrong to have `distance` be a part of a `Vertex`; You can't calculate the distance for two things simultaneously.
8. Re-allocating the `BinaryHeap` so frequently feels like it will be highly inefficient.
9. You are deliberately formatting `Vertex` for output to the user. That means you should use `Display`, not `Debug`
10. Using something like `usize::MAX` to indicate "not visited" is not idiomatic Rust. This conflates two concepts.

```
use std::{
    cell::Cell,
    cmp::Ordering,
    collections::{BinaryHeap, HashMap},
    fmt,
    hash::{Hash, Hasher},
};

fn main() {
    let s = Vertex::new("s");
    let t = Vertex::new("t");
    let x = Vertex::new("x");
    let y = Vertex::new("y");
    let z = Vertex::new("z");

    // A map from vertices to their adjacent vertices including costs
    let mut adjacency_list = HashMap::new();
    adjacency_list.insert(&s, vec![(&t, 10), (&y, 5)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(&t, vec![(&y, 2), (&x, 1)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(&x, vec![(&z, 4)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(&y, vec![(&t, 3), (&x, 9), (&z, 2)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(&z, vec![(&s, 7), (&x, 6)]);

    dijkstra(&s, &adjacency_list);

    adjacency_list.keys().for_each(|v| println!("{}", v));
}

fn dijkstra(
    start: &Vertex<'_>,
    adjacency_list: &HashMap<&Vertex<'_>, Vec<(&Vertex<'_>, usize)>>,
) {
    start.distance.set(0);

    // Fill the binary heap, vertices with the smallest distance go first
    let mut to_visit = BinaryHeap::new();
    adjacency_list.keys().for_each(|v| to_visit.push(*v));

    // We visit the vertices with the smallest distance first, this is
    // what makes Dijkstra a greedy algorithm
    while let Some(v) = to_visit.pop() {
        if let Some(neighbors) = adjacency_list.get(v) {
            for (n, cost) in neighbors {
                let new_distance = v.distance.get() + cost;
                if new_distance < n.distance.get() {
                    n.distance.set(new_distance);
                }
            }
            // When changing a vertex' distance, the BinaryHeap doesn't
            // update the position of the vertex.
            // That's why we create a new heap with the right order.
            let mut new_heap = BinaryHeap::new();
            to_visit.iter().for_each(|x| new_heap.push(*x));
            to_visit = new_heap;
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Eq)]
struct Vertex<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    distance: Cell<usize>,
}

impl<'a> Vertex<'a> {
    fn new(name: &'a str) -> Vertex<'a> {
        Vertex {
            name,
            distance: Cell::new(usize::max_value()),
        }
    }
}
impl<'a> Hash for Vertex<'a> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.name.hash(state);
    }
}

/// Since this Vertex will be put in a priority queue where the vertices
/// with the *smallest* distance should be processed first, `cmp`
/// returns GT if self.distance().get() < other.distance().get()
impl<'a> Ord for Vertex<'a> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Vertex<'a>) -> Ordering {
        other.distance.get().cmp(&self.distance.get())
    }
}
impl<'a> PartialOrd for Vertex<'a> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Vertex<'a>) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}
impl<'a> PartialEq for Vertex<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Vertex<'a>) -> bool {
        self.name == other.name
    }
}

impl<'a> fmt::Display for Vertex<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "name: {}, distance: {}",
            self.name,
            self.distance.get()
        )
    }
}
```

Turning to [petgraph's implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm](https://github.com/bluss/petgraph/blob/master/src/dijkstra.rs) for inspiration, I'd:

- Separate the costs from the graph
- Maintain a list of visited nodes
- Return the distances as a value

```
use std::{
    cmp::Ordering,
    collections::{BinaryHeap, HashMap, HashSet},
};

fn main() {
    let s = Vertex::new("s");
    let t = Vertex::new("t");
    let x = Vertex::new("x");
    let y = Vertex::new("y");
    let z = Vertex::new("z");

    let mut adjacency_list = HashMap::new();
    adjacency_list.insert(s, vec![(t, 10), (y, 5)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(t, vec![(y, 2), (x, 1)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(x, vec![(z, 4)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(y, vec![(t, 3), (x, 9), (z, 2)]);
    adjacency_list.insert(z, vec![(s, 7), (x, 6)]);

    let distances = dijkstra(s, &adjacency_list);

    for (v, d) in &distances {
        println!("name: {}, distance: {}", v.name, d);
    }

    assert_eq!(distances.get(&t), Some(&8));
    assert_eq!(distances.get(&s), Some(&0));
    assert_eq!(distances.get(&y), Some(&5));
    assert_eq!(distances.get(&x), Some(&9));
    assert_eq!(distances.get(&z), Some(&7));
}

fn dijkstra<'a>(
    start: Vertex<'a>,
    adjacency_list: &HashMap<Vertex<'a>, Vec<(Vertex<'a>, usize)>>,
) -> HashMap<Vertex<'a>, usize> {
    let mut distances = HashMap::new();
    let mut visited = HashSet::new();
    let mut to_visit = BinaryHeap::new();

    distances.insert(start, 0);
    to_visit.push(Visit {
        vertex: start,
        distance: 0,
    });

    while let Some(Visit { vertex, distance }) = to_visit.pop() {
        if !visited.insert(vertex) {
            // Already visited this node
            continue;
        }

        if let Some(neighbors) = adjacency_list.get(&vertex) {
            for (neighbor, cost) in neighbors {
                let new_distance = distance + cost;
                let is_shorter = distances
                    .get(&neighbor)
                    .map_or(true, |&current| new_distance < current);

                if is_shorter {
                    distances.insert(*neighbor, new_distance);
                    to_visit.push(Visit {
                        vertex: *neighbor,
                        distance: new_distance,
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    distances
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Vertex<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Vertex<'a> {
    fn new(name: &'a str) -> Vertex<'a> {
        Vertex { name }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Visit<V> {
    vertex: V,
    distance: usize,
}

impl<V> Ord for Visit<V> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        other.distance.cmp(&self.distance)
    }
}

impl<V> PartialOrd for Visit<V> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl<V> PartialEq for Visit<V> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.distance.eq(&other.distance)
    }
}

impl<V> Eq for Visit<V> {}
```

Additional changes:

1. There's no need to take references to `Vertex` if it's only a reference itself. Implement `Copy` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great feedback! Regarding "It feels very wrong to have `Eq` and `Hash` not working from the same data": I agree, but I assumed `derive(Eq)` would look to the `PartialEq` implementation which uses exclusively `name` as its data (just as `Hash` does).